# Find and delete all-zero columns from Numpy array using fancy indexing

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

How do I find columns in a numpy array that are all-zero and then delete them from the array? I'm looking for a way to both get the column indices and then use those indices to delete.

Answer (score 19):

You could use `np.argwhere`, with `np.all` to find your indices. To delete them, use `np.delete`.

**Example**:

Find your `0` columns:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 3, 0],
              [4, 5, 0, 6, 0],
              [7, 8, 0, 9, 0]])

idx = np.argwhere(np.all(a[..., :] == 0, axis=0))

>>> idx
array([[2],
       [4]])
```

Delete your columns

```
a2 = np.delete(a, idx, axis=1)

>>> a2
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution I got

Let say that `OriginMat` is the matrix with the original data,
And the `Result` is the matrix I would like to place the result, Then

```
Result = OriginMat[:,~np.all(OriginMat == 0, axis = 0)]
```

breaking it down it would be

This check over the column(axis 0) whether or not the values are 0
And negates this value so the columns with zero are taken as false

```
~np.all(OriginMat == 0, axis = 0)
```

The resulting matrix would be a vector with False where all elements
are 0 and True when they are not

And the last step just picks the columns that are True(Hence not 0)

I got this solution thanks to the website below:

https://www.science-emergence.com/Articles/How-to-remove-array-rows-that-contain-only-0-in-python/

Comment: This works perfectly and is very elegant, I think it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Some random array of 1's and 0's
x = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(3, 100))
# Find where all values in the columns are zero
mask = (x == 0).all(0)
# Find the indices of these columns
column_indices = np.where(mask)[0]
# Update x to only include the columns where non-zero values occur.
x = x[:,~mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works, simplifying @sacuL's anwer:

```py
$ a = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 3, 0],
              [4, 5, 0, 6, 0],
              [7, 8, 0, 9, 0]])
$ a = a[:, np.any(a, axis=0)]
$ a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```